# Free Shipping Bar In Mini Cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css, mini-cart

I Followed the  tutorial  Add Free Shipping Bar In Mini Cart, Magento 2 https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-free-shipping-bar-in-top-mini-cart/

The progress bar showing but the Title Text is white color https://prnt.sc/1384c5s  Help me

Comment: You can apply the CSS for font color change and it will work.

Comment: i can refer you mageants [magento 2 free shipping bar](https://www.mageants.com/free-shipping-bar-for-magento-2.html) module for your store you can try demo

Answer (score 1):

Please try below css. I believe you used the same class as reference link.

```
.component-wrapper h4, .component-wrapper span{
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: now this working